# REVTeX adds DOI numbers seemingly at random after citations

Tags: natbib, revtex

For some reason, REVTeX seems to *sometimes* add DOI numbers after citations, and sometimes not. It should *never* be doing this, as far as I'm aware. I can't see anything in either bibtex entry that would suggest there's anything unique about entries that get their DOI printed and those which don't. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,10pt]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
Refer to Ref.~\cite{KhaliliAmiri2011} and Ref.~\cite{Yang2011}.
%\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{testbib}
\end{document}
```

with `testbib` as follows:

```
@Article{KhaliliAmiri2011,
  Title                    = {Switching current reduction using perpendicular anisotropy in CoFeB–MgO magnetic tunnel junctions},
  Author                   = {Khalili Amiri, P. and Zeng, Z. M. and Langer, J. and Zhao, H. and Rowlands, G. and Chen, Y.-J. and Krivorotov, I. N. and Wang, J.-P. and Jiang, H. W. and Katine, J. A. and Huai, Y. and Galatsis, K. and Wang, K. L.},
  Journal                  = {Applied Physics Letters},
  Year                     = {2011},
  Number                   = {11},
  Pages                    = {112507},
  Volume                   = {98},

  Doi                      = {10.1063/1.3567780},
  ISSN                     = {0003-6951},
  Publisher                = {AIP Publishing},
  Timestamp                = {2016.02.18}
}
@Article{Yang2011,
  Title                    = { First-principles investigation of the very large perpendicular magnetic anisotropy at Fe | MgO and Co | MgO interfaces },
  Author                   = {Yang, H. X. and Chshiev, M. and Dieny, B. and Lee, J. H. and Manchon, A. and Shin, K. H.},
  Journal                  = {Physical Review B},
  Year                     = {2011},

  Month                    = {Aug},
  Number                   = {5},
  Volume                   = {84},

  Doi                      = {10.1103/physrevb.84.054401},
  ISSN                     = {1550-235X},
  Publisher                = {American Physical Society (APS)},
  Timestamp                = {2016.02.18}
}
```

The (citation) output looks like this for me:

```
[1] P. Khalili Amiri, Z. M. Zeng, J. Langer, H. Zhao, G. Rowlands, Y.-J. Chen, I. N. Krivorotov, J.-P. Wang, H. W. Jiang,
J. A. Katine, Y. Huai, K. Galatsis, and K. L. Wang, Applied Physics Letters 98, 112507 (2011).
[2] H. X. Yang, M. Chshiev, B. Dieny, J. H. Lee, A. Manchon, and K. H. Shin, Physical Review B 84 (2011), 10.1103/phys-
revb.84.054401.
```

Note that the second entry has the DOI printed at the end. I'm going crazy here. I can't figure out why these show up differently. I tried manually changing journal names and publishers to see if it was somehow tied to either one, to no avail. In any case, no APS journal from the Phys. Rev. family lists references with DOI numbers listed in this manner, so I'm really at a loss here.

**Edit:** The problem appears to be that many modern journals (for example anything recent from Physical Review B) do not use "traditional" page numbers, but rather, an article ID. Using various DOI to BibTeX tools, the "Pages" field is blank and the identification number is nowhere to be found. Usually directly using the respective journal's "Export citation" (or equivalent) feature produces BibTeX code which puts the ID in the "Pages" field.

Comment: The second entry has no pages field. This seems to trigger the doi output.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it appears you are correct. Why that's the behavior, I have no idea. I'm not sure why pages are sometimes missing, as I imported my references from DOI's into Jabref. I guess I'll look into repairing missing pages in my references.

Answer (score 7):

Adding an empty pages field like:

```
pages={-}
```

stops REVtex from displaying the DOI numbers in the bibliography.